# Linking to PayPal Express

Tags: expresso-store

I'm trying to send the user off to PayPal Express by way of a single button (design calls for a PayPal button and also a regular checkout), so I have this:

```
    {exp:store:checkout 
        payment_method="paypal_express" 
        return="checkout/confirm/ORDER_HASH"
        require="order_email"
    }

        <div class="fr">
            <label for="inp-login-email" class="fl">Email Address <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="ff">
                <input type="email" name="order_email" id="inp-login-email">
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Checkout with PayPal">

    {/exp:store:checkout}
```

However that bounces me back to the same page I was on before. Presumably I need to add some more info into that form before I can pass to PayPal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a name attribute your submit button. Like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Checkout with Paypal" />
```

Then Store knows that you're looking to finish the checkout and make payment.

Answer (score 2):

PayPal express requires that you pass the users email address before it will allow you to create an order. If you wanted to have a similar experience to your current you would need to have something along the lines of:

```
{exp:store:checkout 
    payment_method="paypal_express" 
    return="checkout/confirm/ORDER_HASH"
}
    <input type="text" name="order_email" placeholder="Your Email Address" />
    <input type="submit" value="Checkout with PayPal">
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

Comment: Does this just mean the email address field for Store needs to be completed by the buyer?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example, but yes Store and PayPal both require that you have at least an email address before you can submit an order.

Comment: I tried this but the page just reloads. I've updated the original question with the updated code